# Solution Configuration but not Platform in VS2010 Toolbar

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I'm running VS2010 premium. One of my teammates has both the solution configuration drop-down (Debug, Release) AND the platform (Win32, x64) combo-boxes in his toolbar. I don't.

For a reference, I'm hoping to see:

[image]

Instead, I only see the first combo-box. What do I need to configure to make the second one appear?

Answer (score 121, accepted):

I had the same issue, here is how I got the menu back

1. On the menubar go to View → Toolbars → Customize...
2. Click on the "Commands" tab
3. Select the "Toolbar" radio button and find "Standard" in the drop down list
   [image: Customize dialog]
4. Click the "Add Command..." button
5. Select the "Build" category
6. Find and select the "Solution Platforms" command and click "OK"
   [image: Add Command dialog]
7. Move your new command to a comfortable place on your toolbar using "Move Up" and "Move Down"
8. Enjoy not having to dig through Solution Properties to change the platform

Comment: I agree that this should be visible by default!

Comment: This has bugged me for so long time now. Thank you!

Comment: This *is* visible by default. The only way it could have disappeared is if you've removed it (or perhaps imported settings that removed it). The process to get it back is convoluted because you're customizing a toolbar, which is inherently an "expert" feature. Even if you could simplify it further, it would hardly be worth the effort.

Comment: @CodyGray this is visible by default, for example, if you use C# settings configuration but it's not if you choose vb.net settings. Said that, it happened also to me that it disappeared without any apparent reason.

Answer (score 1):

in my case the toolbar was not showing.
the above answer helped me find a simpler solution

VIEW > Toolbars > `✓` Standard

Comment: This is the way it should work, but for some reason it does not in a lot of cases.